# Responsive table on mobile with max widths

Tags: html, css

Having an issue with this table structure. On mobile if they're two columns then it's ok but sometimes the client may want up to 5. So on mobile I'm looking for an x-scroll system. I got that working but having trouble keeping the 's having a min/max width if the content is multiple sentences. If 3-4+ columns may only be 2-3 small words per line and doesn't look good.

So the goal, on mobile, is to keep this columns more than just being 33% if it's 3 columns, 25% if 4, and so on. Would like, on mobile, if it's more than 3 columns to have each column at least 40%...for example. Expand the columns a bit so everything isn't scrunched but does make line breaks after a certain % and thte user can scroll x to see the rest of content.

```css
.wp-block-table {
  width: 100%;
}

table {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

td,
th,
tr {
  padding: 16px 24px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
}

tr {
  height: 52px;
}

tr:first-child {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 56px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
}


}
```

```html
<figure class="wp-block-table">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>quam id</td>
        <td>iaculis eu</td>
        <td>quis</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Smartly hulk pirate avast mutiny jury mast mizzen doubloon Brethren of the Coast aft.Draught loaded to the gunwalls shrouds Spanish Main deadlights jury mast jib come about crow’s nest long boat.</td>
        <td>Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada. Dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque habitant morbi tristique.&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Jib scurvy bilged on her anchor ballast Arr topgallant gaff Yellow Jack stern long clothes.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec.&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Et sollicitudin ac orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque.&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Fire ship Sink me hardtack hearties league lass Privateer Nelsons folly broadside rum.&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Fire ship Sink me hardtack hearties league lass Privateer Nelsons folly broadside rum.&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Consectetur lorem donec massa sapien faucibus. Ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean et. <br>Fusce id velit ut tortor. Enim nec dui nunc mattis enim ut.</td>
        <td>Handsomely log cable mutiny pirate doubloon nipperkin bilge rat overhaul yard.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ac turpis egestas integer eget aliquet. Ut sem viverra aliquet eget sit.&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Ut sem viverra aliquet eget sit. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada.</td>
        <td>Smartly hulk pirate avast mutiny jury mast mizzen doubloon Brethren of the Coast aft. <br>Draught loaded to the gunwalls shrouds Spanish Main deadlights jury mast jib come about crow’s nest long boat.</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best and the easiest way to determine width inside table cells with px instead of percentage of the parent.

Just add the following code to your CSS

```
td{
  min-width: 300px;
}
```